# Azure Devops YML Template Conditions and Dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a requirement for a couple of job templates but I can’t get the conditions and dependencies configured to run how I want. I have the basic yaml below:

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: Environment
- name: action
  values:
    - deploy
    - undeploy
    - redeploy
  default: redeploy
  
stages:
- stage: app
  displayName: App
  jobs:
  - deployment: kickoff
    environment:
      name: ${{  parameters.environment }}
      resourceType: virtualMachine
      tags: app
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - powershell: Write-Host "Run kickoff tasks"
  - template: undeploy.yml
    parameters:
      environment: ${{  parameters.environment }}
      action: ${{  parameters.action }}
  - template: deploy.yml
    parameters:
      environment: ${{  parameters.environment }}
      action: ${{  parameters.action }}
```

The requirements I have are the below:

- Undeploy.yml: if Action = ‘Deploy’, does not run. If Action = ‘Undeploy’, only run this template. Action = ‘Redeploy’, run both templates but undeploy.yml must run first.
- Deploy.yml: If Action = ‘Deploy’, only run this template. If Action = ‘Undeploy’, does not run. If Action = ‘Redeploy’, run both templates but deploy.yml must run second.

Closest I can get to is setting the templates yaml as below:

undeploy.yml

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  default: environmentToDeployTo
- name: action
  values:
    - deploy
    - undeploy
    - redeploy
  default: redeploy

jobs:
  - deployment: undeploy
    dependsOn: kickoff
    condition: ne ('${{parameters.action}}', 'deploy')
    environment:
      name: ${{  parameters.environment }}
      resourceType: virtualMachine
      tags: app
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          #undeploy steps here#
```

deploy.yml

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  default: environmentToDeployTo
- name: action
  values:
    - deploy
    - undeploy
    - redeploy
  default: redeploy

jobs:
  - deployment: dploy
    dependsOn: undeploy
    condition: ne ('${{parameters.action}}', 'undeploy')
    environment:
      name: ${{  parameters.environment }}
      resourceType: virtualMachine
      tags: app
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          #dploy steps here#
```

This results only affects deploy.yml but it is not able to run in isolation - the undeploy.yml job template will have to run beforehand. However, without the "dependsOn", I can see no other way to ensure that undeploy.yml runs first.

Is there anyway to achieve this as per requirements outlined above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be useful to see more of the templates. It also wouldn't hurt to see the expanded template (from the pipeline YML itself, hit the hamburger and download the full YML - it will expand the templates out, and can be useful in debugging)

Comment: Couldn't find the burger icon, but I've copied the yaml into the original post

Answer (score 0):

`dependsOn` takes the name of a stage or job as input, not the name of a template file. Seeing more of your templates would be useful, but if you could use the name of the stage or job in dependsOn, you might get the result you're looking for.

Think of the expanded template as your guide here - you can refer to a stage or job that's declared in a different template, so long as it expands to the right place when the pipeline runs.

Comment: Apologies, I initally mentioned the template file to avoid any confusion. I reality, I had the the job name as the 'dependsOn'. i have pasted a cut down down version of the yamls, and removed the additional deployment tasks that run the install/uninstall.

Comment: Have you tried a condition like `ne (parameters.action, 'undeploy')` ?